# clean mounted docker folder with shutil.rmtree(dir)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, mount, shutil, mount-point

When I clean [ `shutil.rmtree(dir_name)`] mounted folder (docker) on Ubuntu 18 then files are not visible from docker in mount dir [`/app`] after that, but the same approach works fine for MacOS.
Following command used to mount a directory:
`docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source=dir_name,target=/app image_name`

There are no errors on the docker side but looks like the mount stop working.
Looks like an issue with shutil.rmtree, but I'm not sure. Is it a docker or shutil lib issue?

Steps to reproduce:

Create dir:
`mkdri /tmp/mount_dir`
`touch /tmp/mount_dir/test.txt`

`docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/mount_dir,target=/app ubuntu`
docker> `ls /app`
`test.txt`

Then run python script `pyhton3.9 example.py`:
`import shutil import os shutil.rmtree("/tmp/mount_dir") os.mkdir("/tmp/mount_dir") os.mkdir("/tmp/mount_dir/test_one")`

Go to Docker:
docker>`ls /app`
test_one (when everything running on MacOS)

The empty result on Ubuntu. Mount doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], including the application code itself, the `docker run` command(s), and how you're verifying the difference on both hosts?  What's the behavior you expect?

Comment: @DavidMaze added steps to the post